# lightning:inputAddress With Country Picklists

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, address

I am using the below lightning:inputAddress and specifically want to make the country field a dropdown/picklist. I am returning a map value from the apex method. But the values are not being populated to the country dropdown. Seems I am unable to bind the values to the countryOptions attribute. Can someone please help me here?

```
<aura:attribute name="country" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="countryOptions" type="List"/>
<lightning:inputAddress class="slds-m-bottom_small"
                                        addressLabel="Shipping Address"
                                        streetLabel="Street"
                                        cityLabel="City"
                                        countryLabel="Country"
                                        provinceLabel="State"
                                        postalCodeLabel="Postal Code"
                                        street="{!v.requestRecord.Shipping_Address__c}"
                                        city="{!v.requestRecord.City__c}"
                                        country="{! v.country}"
                                        province="{!v.requestRecord.State__c}"
                                        postalCode="{!v.requestRecord.Zip_Code__c}"
                                        countryOptions="{! v.countryOptions}"
                                        required="true"
                                        disabled="False"
                                        fieldLevelHelp="{!v.shippingAddressTooltip}"
                />
```

Now in JS, I am trying to bind the value like below

```
doInit : function (component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.getCountryCode');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var resp = response.getReturnValue();
            var countryList = [];
            for(var key in resp){
                countryList.push([{'label': resp[key], 'value': key}]);
            }
            component.set("v.countryOptions", countryList);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Here is my apex method-

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, String> getCountryCode() {
    Map<String, String> countryCodeMap = new Map<String, String>();
    for(Country_Code__c ccm : [Select Country__c, CountryCode__c from Country_Code__c Limit 3]){
        countryCodeMap.put(ccm.Country__c, ccm.CountryCode__c);
    }
    return countryCodeMap;
}
```

Comment: I see a typo err in `cmponent.set("v.countryOptions", countryList);` i.e. `cmponent` (instead of `component`). May be that's causing the problem. Have you also tried observing the `countryList` values via console.log?

Comment: Hi @arut thanks for your helpful comment here. "countryList"  is coming like "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]." It means data are coming. But the country picklist is showing blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove square brackets in controller

Replace `countryList.push([{'label': resp[key], 'value': key}]);` with

`countryList.push({'label': resp[key], 'value': key});`

Change Mapping

```
countryCodeMap.put(ccm.CountryCode__c,ccm.Country__c,);
```